# Why does '/opt/local/bin' takes precedence over '/bin' despite `$PATH`?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, environment-variables

Bash that comes with macOS is of version `3.2.57` (the '/bin/bash'), however, I also have Bash version `5.1.12` which lives in '/opt/local/bin'.
I'm interested in why the latter is used when I execute 'bash' despite that '/bin' goes after '/opt/local/bin' in the `$PATH` variable?

Comment: the PATH is read from left to right

Comment: (1) The comment above is correct: the first match is used, so `/opt/local/bin` being first means that it's _expected_ to take precedence. (2) This question is better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow, being a question about how UNIX tools work rather than a question about the practice of software development.

Comment: Ooh, I got it! Thank you!

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question, btw. I still expect the question to be closed as off-topic after more folks vote, but until/unless there's consensus reached to that effect, nothing wrong with undeleting and accepting your own answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the $PATH is read from left to right and the first match takes precedence